# boost.asio async_write/read before async_connect finished

Tags: boost, boost-asio

Say first I call `async_connect` on a newly constructed `tcp::socket`. Before the handler of `async_connect` is called, I call `async_read/write`s on the same socket. Will them wait for the connection or fail immediately because the socket has not connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `async_connect` performs asynchronously, your scenario has race-condition - so it may occasionally work or fail, depending on timings. In order to begin async. i/o on a socket, one should wait first for `async_connect` completion handler - just like described in the Asio documentation.

That's said, you can design a class that will accept async. operations as functors, store them in a queue, and internally chain/invoke them in the correct order.